# Passing an array/list of integers from Python to C#

Tags: c#, python, arrays, python-2.7, int

I have been trying to pass an array/list of integers from Python to C# and I keep encountering the same error:

> Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '',
>   namespace ''. '.

This is the C# code that I am trying to pass my list of integers to:

```
void SimpleSetFunction(int foo, List<int> bar);
```

In Python, I have tried to pass it in many ways and they have all **failed**, returning the previously stated error. Examples of what I have tried:

```
client.service.SimpleSetFunction(1,[0,1,2]) #fails

client.service.SimpleSetFunction(1,['0','1','2']) #fails
```

The only way I was able to pass a list to SimpleSetFunction was to call the Simple**Get**Function first, and then pass the result to SimpleSetFunction.

The SimpleGetFunction would return something like this:

```
(ArrayOfint)
{
   int[] =
      1,
      2,
}
```

Which I could now pass to the Set function, like so:

```
foo = client.service.SimpleGetFunction()
client.service.SimpleGetFunction(1,foo) #works
```

The problem with such a thing, of course, is that I can only set something which is already there. I can't add any new integers to the list.

So, how do I pass the integers I want to the C# list?

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\SimpleGet.py", l
ine 228, in <module>
    test_test()
  File "<path>\SimpleGet.py", l
ine 81, in test_test
    client.service.SimpleSetFunction(1,1)
  File "<path>\client.py"
, line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "<path>\client.py"
, line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "<path>\client.py"
, line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "<path>\client.py"
, line 702, in failed
    r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
  File "<path>\binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)

suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The formatter threw an exception while tryi
ng to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize pa
rameter http://tempuri.org/:channels. The InnerException message was 'Error in l
ine 1 position 351. Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name ''
, namespace ''. '.  Please see InnerException for more details.'
```

SimpleGet.py:

```
import sys
import array
import time
from suds.client import Client
from array import array

def test_test():
    wsdl = 'http://*<URL>*/*<URL>*?wsdl'
    client = Client(wsdl)
    result = client.service.IsAlive()
    if result == "true":
        print "Alive"

    getResult = client.service.SimpleGetFunction(1)
    setFunction = client.service.SimpleSetFunction(1,**????**)
```

Comment: Are you using IronPython, or, plain python? There are multiple techniques...which one you are using isn't clear...

Comment: I think (if that's possible) that you should change parameter type from `List<int>` to `int[]` and this will work.

Comment: @deostroll I am using plain Python. I have tried using IronPython but it is throwing a ton of other errors.

Comment: @m.rogalski If I was able to change the C# code I definitely would have. Unfortunately, I am using this C# code as an API, and I do not own the original code.

Comment: Please be clear on how that api inter operates with python...you can use ilspy to deassemble the assembly whereby you can see for yourself whats going on...

Comment: @deostroll I do not have access to the C# files at all, thus I can't run ILSpy. Could you please specify what exactly is it that you need? The project is huge and consists of hundreds (if not thousands) of files, so I obviously can't post it all here. I'll be happy to share part of it if you could direct me to what exactly is it that you're looking for. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What about a stacktrace at least?

Comment: @deostroll I have uploaded the Traceback that was thrown, I hope this is indeed what you meant. Please note that I DO have access to all of those .py files, so if needed I can access them.

Comment: Okay...it looks like you are trying to get your python program to communicate with a WCF service. The python lib you are using is "suds". The wcf is probably hosted over HTTP and the data exchange format is SOAP. The error is due to an incorrect SOAP message being generated. Please share the code for `SimpleGet.py`

Comment: @deostroll You are correct indeed. SimpleGet.py consists of the code that I am writing, it's where I am trying to pass the integer to C#, so I am not quite sure why you want to see it again. I've updated the main message with the full code, though I do not think it is what you meant and it probably won't assist you much.

Comment: perhaps you should have a look at this and give it a try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23710049/145682

Comment: @deostroll Seems like in the example you gave me, he is trying to pass it directly from Python to the WCF service, however, I need to pass the list to a C# code, and it would pass it to the WCF service. My problem is having this list passed to C#, so unfortunately that wasn't it.. Anything else you think might assist?

Comment: You said `"...I need to pass the list to a C# code, and it would pass it to the WCF service"` why you do say _you've to pass to c# code_? What is that you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trivial tip.

When you host a simple WCF service where one of the methods accepts some IEnumerable (i.e. typed arrays in some sense), you have to let suds consume the wsdl and create a proxy client. If you print the client you'd get some idea regarding methods you can invoke and their arguments.

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "<svc url>/?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
print client
```

This will hopefully give you an output about what you can do with the client.

[image]

Here my wcf service had a method called `EchoNumbers` which accepted an array of integers. You have to create that type in your python code for consumption.

So here is sample code for that:

```
from suds.client import Client

def main():
    url = "http://localhost:1308/Service1.svc?wsdl"

    client = Client(url)
    ArrayOfint = client.factory.create('ns2:ArrayOfint')
    ArrayOfint.int = [1,2,3]
    res = client.service.EchoNumbers(ArrayOfint)
    print res.string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, it helped a lot! Solved my issue. Just to understand better, how is creating the object ArrayOfInt different than creating a simply array, such as: foo = []? They are both arrays. Why is one working and the other isn't? Python treats "foo" differently?

Comment: Python list are not typed. Suds requires someway to generate the right soap envelope to issue to the wcf service and get response. Most of this is  outlined by the WSDL spec.